# How to make Ansible run one certain task only on one host?

Tags: ansible

The playbook looks like:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "run on all hosts,1"
      shell: something1
    - name: "run on all hosts,2"
      shell: something2
    - name: "run on one host, any host would do"
      shell: this_command_should_run_on_one_host
    - name: "run on all hosts,3"
      shell: something3
```

I know with command line option `--limit`, I can limit to one host.
Is it possible to do it in playbook?

Comment: Add `run_once: true` to the task.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

For any host (with defaults it will match the first on the list):

```yaml
- name: "run on first found host"
  shell: this_command_should_run_on_one_host
  run_once: true
```

For a specific host:

```yaml
- name: "run on that_one_host host"
  shell: this_command_should_run_on_one_host
  when: ansible_hostname == 'that_one_host'
```

Or `inventory_hostname` (hostname as defined in the Ansible inventory) instead of `ansible_hostname` (hostname as defined on the target machine), depending on which name you want to use.

Comment: very useful, but unfortunately does not apply to all ansible modules.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi What do you mean?

Comment: Worth pointing out that @techraf put some characters in their answer that won't work. Change `‘that_one_host’` to `'that_one_host'` (changing `’` for `'` )

Comment: You can also do `when: inventory_hostname == play_hosts[0]` to run only on one host. Then you can use `when: inventory_hostname != play_hosts[0]` to run a task on all other hosts.

Comment: @kjpc-tech that's an awesome trick for cluster conf.

Comment: To run just on the last host: `when: inventory_hostname == play_hosts[play_hosts|length - 1|int]`

Answer (score 22):

Techraf's [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47342906/4175504) is the exact one for the OP's question.

I just wanted to show a better way to run a task on a specific host:

```yaml
- name: "run on that_one_host host"
  shell: this_command_should_run_on_one_host
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: that_one_host
```

If the group the playbook is run on contains many hosts, using `when: ansible_hostname == 'that_one_host'` or `when: ansible_hostname == ansible_play_hosts[0]` will evaluate the when-clause on all the hosts (which could be long if the when-clause had other more complicated conditions) and result in a long list of skipped hosts in the playbook's output.

Combining `run_once` and `delegate_to`, the playbook's output will be cleaner, only showing the task being executed on the chosen host.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Run on one specific host | when-clause
      debug:
        msg: "Hello world"
      when: inventory_hostname == ansible_play_hosts[0]
    
    - name: Run on one specific host | run_once + delegate_to
      debug:
        msg: "Hello world"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: ansible_play_hosts[0]
```

```
TASK [Run on one specific host | when-clause] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [host2]
skipping: [host3]
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "Hello world"
}
skipping: [host4]

TASK [Run on one specific host | run_once + delegate_to] ***********************************************************************
ok: [host2 -> ansible_play_hosts[0]] => {
    "msg": "Hello world"
}
```

Whichever solution you choose, never combine these, if you want a task to be run once on a precise host:

- `run_once: true` and
- `when: inventory_hostname == 'that_one_host'`

If you do, it will be impossible to know in advance if the task will be executed or not (I have learnt it the hard way). The reason is that `run_once: true` will select a random host in the play's group and only later apply the when-clause:

- if run_once selected to run the task on 'that_one_host', the task will be executed
- if run_once selected 'another_host', the task will be skipped.

Comment: play_hosts is now deprecated, what I understand we should use ansible_play_batch ?

Comment: @BenjaminD: you are right, thank you. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

**True way**

```yaml
- include_tasks: custom-tasks.yml
  when: inventory_hostname == item
  with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it is, this play runs all the tasks in custom-tasks.yml on the first host, then runs them on the second and so on, on *all* the hosts in the current play.
I cannot see how it might help answer the OP's question.