# How to make ansible task run on only one host? for each app

Tags: ansible

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47342724/3317808) did not help.

The playbook looks like:

```
- name: play1
  hosts:
    - all
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: someteam
  roles:
    - role: role1
    - role: role2
    - role: role3
      when: apps_var|length > 0
```

Specifically for `role3`, In `../roles/role3/tasks/main.yml`, the tasks look like:

```
- block:

    - include: “deploy1.yml app={{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ apps_list | intersect(complete_list) }}"

    - include: deploy2.yml app={{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ complete_list }}"

  when: complete_list|length > 0
```

---

We want to run `deploy1.yml` tasks for every `{{ apps_list | intersect(complete_list) }}` on only one host but not `all`.

Problem is, we cannot take out this task(`deploy1.yml`) from `role3`

We are using ansible 2.3

---

Does `run_once` help at task level? to deploy every app(in `with_items`) but on only one host...

Comment: Can we segregate the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: "We want to run deploy1.yml tasks for every {{ apps_list | intersect(complete_list) }} on only one host. Does run_once help at task level? to deploy every app(in with_items) but on only one host?"

A: Yes. It does. The tasks below

```
$ cat roles/role3/tasks/main.yml
- block:
    - include_tasks: deploy1.yml
      vars:
        app: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ apps_list | intersect(complete_list) }}"
      run_once: yes
    - include: deploy2.yml
      vars:
        app: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ complete_list }}"
  when: complete_list|length > 0

$ cat roles/role3/tasks/deploy1.yml 
- debug:
    msg: 'role3: deploy1, app: {{ app }}'

$ cat roles/role3/tasks/deploy2.yml 
- debug:
    msg: 'role3: deploy2, app: {{ app }}'
```

with inventory

```
all:
  hosts:
    test_01:
    test_02:
    test_03:
```

and the playbook

```
- name: play1
  hosts: all
  vars:
    apps_list: [A, C]
    complete_list: [A, B, C]
  roles:
    - role: role1
    - role: role2
    - role: role3
      when: apps_list|length > 0
```

give (abridged)

```
[...]
TASK [role3 : debug] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy1, app: A"
}

TASK [role3 : debug] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy1, app: C"
}
[...]
TASK [role3 : debug] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: A"
}
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: A"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: A"
}

TASK [role3 : debug] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: B"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: B"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: B"
}

TASK [role3 : debug] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: C"
}
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: C"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": "role3: deploy2, app: C"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

---

Notes

1) loop_control can be used

```
- include_tasks: deploy1.yml
  loop: "{{ apps_list | intersect(complete_list) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: app
```

2) run_once works also in the whole block

```
- block:
  ...
  when: complete_list|length > 0
  run_once: yes
```

Comment: Can I say, `run_once`  at block level is more readable than task level?

Comment: Yes. You can. If this is what you want.

Comment: I segregated into two blocks and made it more readable, because there is some initialization code as well.